# OpenWRT + LibreNMS: get number of wireless clients via snmpd

Tags: snmp, openwrt

I want to see the number of wireless clients connected to my openWRT Accesspoints on my LibreNMS-Installation.

Out of the box this does not work, so I added this to /etc/config/snmpd

```
config exec
    option name clientNumber 
    option prog /usr/bin/wireless-count.sh
    option miboid 1.3.6.1.4.1.14125.2.1.1.15.8 

config exec
    option name clientNumber5G
    option prog /usr/bin/wireless-count5.sh
    option miboid 1.3.6.1.4.1.14125.2.1.1.16.8
```

the result is the following lines are added to /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf:

```
exec 1.3.6.1.4.1.14125.2.1.1.15.8 clientNumber /usr/bin/wireless-count.sh 
exec 1.3.6.1.4.1.14125.2.1.1.16.8 clientNumber5G /usr/bin/wireless-count5.sh
```

The wireless-count.sh script lookes like this (the 5GHz accordingly):

```
echo "$(iwinfo phy1-ap0 assoclist)" "$(iwinfo phy1-ap1 assoclist)" | grep -o 'RX: ' | wc -l
```

It prints the Number of connected clients and should work.

But LibreNMS does not show me the Number of wireless clients. I did try another OID (.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.50).

The ideas came from those sites:

script and config: http://www.guiguishow.info/categorie/hardware/embarque/openwrt/

oid: https://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/help-center/en-US/Content/en-US/WG-Cloud/Devices/access_point/ap_snmp.html

But it does not work. I think the OID might be wrong or the concept as such does not work.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I think this question is not about programming and belongs to https://superuser.com/